# Trying to post through Channel form anonymously - "The provided member id to use for guest submissions is invalid."

Tags: safecracker

[image]I'm trying to get Channel From working with non logged in users. Unfortunately with no success. I have

```
{exp:channel:form channel="calendar_events" return="site/index" logged_out_member_id="3"}
```

When I try this logged in - it works. When I'm logged out - it says

> The provided member id to use for guest submissions is invalid.

Does anybody experienced these problems with channel form and anonymously posting en entry?

p.s. I allowed the Guest submission in the CP admin -> Channel Form page.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Would be useful to post the fix if you fond it :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to this I beleive you have to allow the group access to the specific channel you want them to post too. I just tested this on my sandbox...

So after you've done your thing in `Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Form`, head over to `Members > Member Groups`, click 'edit group' for the Guests Row, scroll down to the "Channel Assignment" section (quite near the bottom) and for the channel they are posting to select 'Yes'.

I beleive this should get you rocking, let us know if there's any more issue!

Comment: Yeah, sure I did this - thank you for noticing, but this still comes with the same error message. 
[Here is the page from the member group settings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7yqics1zlvjsvi/channel-assignment.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Aha, the plot thickens! Have you got an author field in your channel form? (A snippet of your form might be useful here), also have you tried without `logged_out_member_id="3"`? I believe this parameter might be forcing the author to user 3, who isn't a guest, obviously. What group is user 3 a member of??

Comment: I'm noticing the fact that I'm actually hardcoding the author id in the hidden fields. And yes I did tried without the logged out parameters

Comment: Actually I have `author_id` field which is set to "1" in hidden fields on  different layer. But I don't think this is the problem at all. Removing the `logged_out` parameter doesn't work as well. member group 3 is Guests, my member, which is set to author of the post is from this group